# Rails edit migration file to include index?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've just been trying to figure out some ways to optimize my MySQL database, but I'm having a bit of an issue with indexing here.

As opposed to stacking up a bunch of migration files (since I'm not really managing much data yet), I'm simply "going back" and editing migration files periodically to include columns, etc. Not sure if this is best practice, but I figured it'd be easier to avoid ending up with 100 migration files adding small things.

Anyways, I'm trying to add an index to one of the columns in a migration file, but I can't seem to get it to work (it's not showing up in the schema file after rolling back and migrating again).

```
class CreateVuln < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :vuln do |t|
      t.integer :node_id
      t.string :node_identifier
      t.string :vuln_finding_identifier

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :vuln, :node_identifier
  end
end
```

But when I go to schema.rb, here's what it looks like:

```
  create_table "vuln", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "node_id",                 limit: 4
    t.string   "node_identifier",         limit: 255
    t.string   "vuln_finding_identifier", limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               null: false
  end
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? If I add a new migration by running `rails g migration AddIndexToVuln node_identifier:string:index` then I can see that the schema.rb file gets updated properly. schema.rb then adds this line:   `add_index "vuln", ["node_identifier"], name: "index_vuln_on_node_identifier", using: :btree`

So as opposed to creating a new migration file, I'm just wondering if I can just roll back my database and make the changes in the existing migration file for that table.

Comment: Not sure why but it looks like the space above "above_index" caused it not to work. Very strange. Got it working now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your migration so the first thing to check is whether `rake db:rollback` actually succeeds. If you ran the rollback *after* adding the `add_index` line then the rollback should fail since Rails will attempt a `remove_index` on a non-existent index. If the rollback fails, the fix is simple. Comment out the `add_index` line and run `rake db:rollback`, uncomment the line and then run `rake db:migrate`.

If you're in the early stages of development and truly don't care about the data, you can run `rake db:reset` which will drop the db and rebuild starting with the first migration.

All that being said, there is absolutely nothing wrong with creating new migrations (no matter how small) to modify the schema - this is their intended purpose. Sooner or later you will get to a point where rolling back and modifying migrations just won't scale so just embrace the approach from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to first understand what's going on with your migration.

So, Rails uses timestamps to track the changes in your migration, so when you run rake db:migrate, Rails would first look at the `schema.rb` to check the current state of the your db. You would have seen this kind of line in your schema file: `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160625234411) do`, all migrations are versioned by a timestamp in this fashion.

Therefore, it would only run any new migration, i.e whose timestamp is greater than that on the schema file.

So, that's reason you should actually generate a new migration if you want to change the state of your db, otherwise, you would have to keep doing `rake db:[drop|reset]` etc everytime to get things working.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been doing. Resetting. Since it's fairly new and inserting sample data isn't that big of a task, I've been doing this as opposed to creating numerous new migration files.